# Multiple footable initialization inside bootstrap tab works only for one table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, footable

I have 2 tables in each tab in bootstrap tab with hidden divs active when tab is clicked. The default tab works fine. But the rest of the tab behaves absurd. I tried following code:-

```
$('#tradeswith').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function () {
        $('.footable').trigger('footable_initialize');           

});
```

But the problem here is it works only for one table. For the rest of the table it doesn't work.

Comment: A fiddle or plunk would help.  Here's a plunk you can fork to get started: http://plnkr.co/edit/mgmZeLR7ud5x4g0RLBRv.

Comment: Would it be possible you've tried use `$('.footable').trigger('footable_redraw');`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post and much too late to solve the OP's problem but I arrived at this page with the same issue. Hopefully my answer will help the next person who arrives here.

The problem is that on non active tabs they have a CSS value of `display: none` which means the dimensions of the table is returned as 0 when Footable is initialized which causes problems.

The solution to this is to trigger a resize on selecting a new tab.

```
$('#tradeswith').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function () {
    $('.footable').trigger('footable_resize');
});
```

This will also work with other tab solutions, you just need to listen for the triggered event.